# When Running javac and javah in cmd, it shows javac: file not found

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to run my java simple which can print "111" in eclipse IDE but when I'm trying to run it in CMD, it show error like:

```
javac: file not found: testdll.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

But I already cd to this path:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\src>javac testdll.java
```

My .java file path is:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\src\testdll.java`
```

.class file is :

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\bin\testdll.class`
```

When I'm running java -version it shows:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

When I'm running javac -version:

```
javac 1.8.0_40
```

When I'm running echo %path%:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin;
```

I've searched many pages about this problem but it doesn't work with my issue.
I'm not sure what the reason. Can anybody can help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Double check that the file exists in that directory. Next, is it actually in a package? Also, did you really name your *eclipse* workspace ***elipse*workspace**?

Comment: @user3622390 Are you able to compile a java program outside of the eclipse workspace!

Comment: follow standards of java, make the classname same as filename! though this is not the solution for the problem- just want you to understand about the standards and specifications.

Comment: is that `testdll.class` file is generated? If it is generated at `C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\bin\testdll.class` then how can you say javac is not working. is there any error coming up.

Comment: run "dir" and check again file is really exist on that location, I just think you are in wrong directory

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch Thank you. It;s in a package. Is it ok with name of workspace? I can change it anyway.

Comment: @09Q71AO534 It can not run outside of the eclipse workspace, and the .class file is generated, lclass name is the same with file name. Thank you

Comment: @Tech-Sira I'm sure that is the correct directory. When you run dir, you can see the testdll file here. Thank you

Comment: @user3622390 So what is the problem that you are having now? You have your `.class` file with you and you can `run` that class file `java testdll`

Comment: @09Q71AO534 The problem is I can run it in IDE but when I use CMD, no matter  java, javac ,javah testdll.java, it shows file can't find. When running java testdll.java it doesn't work.

Comment: yes! it doesn't work, because your class files will be stored in `C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\bin\testdll.class`, If you want to run the testdll from cmd then u have 2 options 1> you can cd to `C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\bin` and run `java testdll`. 2>Set the classpath and then use `java testdll`

Comment: @user3622390 compile using classpath `java -classpath  C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\bin\;C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\src testdll `

Comment: dont try to run as `java testdll.java` only run `java testdll`

Comment: @user3622390 Let me know it resolves your problem or not!

Comment: What is the package?

Comment: @09Q71AO534 Thank you for your patient, when I cd to C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\bin and run java testdll, it shows :Error: Could not find or load main class testdll. I don't very understand the classpath you mentioned, is that the environmental variable which is .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the package name is the same as the project name, testdll.

Comment: @user3622390 Can you please attach the `testdll.java` file, just to check the reference. Because i tried the same way creating a project in eclipse and then compiled it is all good working in y system. Just to make sure!

Comment: @09Q71AO534 'package testdll;

public class testdll {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("1111");

 }

}' Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you commented i considered the below `testdll` as your source file.

```
package testdll; 

    public class testdll {
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        System.out.println("1111");
        }
    }
```

> **If you are trying to compile and run outside of Eclipse IDE use the below process.**

*Go to the path* `cd C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\src\testdll\`

*Compile*   : `javac testdll.java`

*Run/Execute*   :

- We cannot run a Package definition file from inside the package.

  - Come out of the package use : `cd..`
  - Now you are in the `src` directory `C:\Users\user\Documents\elipseworkspace\testdll\src\`, so now you can run the `.class` file of testdll as : `java testdll.testdll` **(java package_name.class_name)**

Comment: I'm following your way, but it still shows:C:\Users\kun\Documents\workspace\testdll\src>java testdll.testdll
Error: Could not find or load main class testdll.testdll. Is there anything wrong? Thank you

Comment: @user3622390 Did you compile the `testdll.java`? using `javac` or else from `eclipse`

Comment: @user3622390 i tried compiling in both the ways and i am able to view the output `1111`

Comment: This is what i had tried and [It worked as a charm](http://s22.postimg.org/s2i7nqq1t/When_Running_javac_and_javah_in_cmd_it_shows_ja.png)

Comment: @ 09Q71AO534 Yes, I compile this, it does show 1111 in IDE, When I use javac compile it, it shows that error. I haven't meet this problem before, Do you think I should reinstall JDK?

Comment: @user3622390 Please delete the existing folder from eclipse and then create a new project again and then try the same. Please keep a note on the steps that you do! If you are not able to compile it again from command prompt please let me know(attach the steps you followed). No need to re-install JDK :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I reinstall JDK and crate a new project. It works. I didn;t get the reason but that works. Thanks all.

Comment: @user3622390 Cool :) No Mention